# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 200, 66, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (?, 66, 200, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow

My development environment is windows and I encountered a error while executing my code. How can I fix this?

The result below is the output when running **train.py**.

**Error generated while executing code:**

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 200, 66, 3) for Tensor Placeholder:0, which has shape (?, 66, 200, 3)`

The inside of the data.csv file is saved in the following format.

**data.csv**

> img_2022-07-30_16-12-38_0.jpg,2

**train.py**

```
import os
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2
import driving_data
import model
import numpy as np
import time

begin = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

LOGDIR = './save'

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

L2NormConst = 0.001

train_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

start_learning_rate = 0.5e-3
adjust_learning_rate = 1e-5

onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.reshape(tf.cast(model.y_, tf.int32),[-1]), depth=4)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy( onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=model.y)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(start_learning_rate).minimize(loss)

loss_val = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy( onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=model.y)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)

tf.summary.scalar("loss_val", loss_val)

merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = tf.train.SaverDef.V2)

logs_path = './logs'
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

epochs = 13
batch_size = 100

for epoch in range(epochs):
  for i in range(int(driving_data.num_images/batch_size)):
    xs, ys = driving_data.LoadTrainBatch(batch_size)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={model.x: xs, model.y_: ys, model.keep_prob: 0.7})
    loss_value = loss.eval(feed_dict={model.x: xs, model.y_: ys, model.keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("Epoch: %d, Step: %d, Loss: %g" % (epoch, i, loss_value))


    if i % 10 == 0:
      xs_val, ys_val = driving_data.LoadValBatch(batch_size)
      loss_val = loss.eval(feed_dict={model.x:xs_val, model.y_: ys_val, model.keep_prob: 1.0})
      print("Epoch: %d, Step: %d, Loss_val: %g" % (epoch, i, loss_val))

    summary = merged_summary_op.eval(feed_dict={model.x:xs, model.y_: ys, model.keep_prob: 1.0})
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch * driving_data.num_images/batch_size + i)

    if i % batch_size == 0:
      if not os.path.exists(LOGDIR):
        os.makedirs(LOGDIR)
      checkpoint_path = os.path.join(LOGDIR, "model.ckpt")
      filename = saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path)
      print("Model saved in file: %s" % filename)


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(onehot_labels, 1), tf.argmax(model.y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print('Train Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={model.x: xs, model.y_: ys, model.keep_prob: 1.0}))
print('Validation Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={model.x: xs_val, model.y_: ys_val, model.keep_prob: 1.0}))

end = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
print('begin: ', begin)
print('end: ', end)

print("Run the command line:\n" \
          "--> tensorboard --logdir=./logs --port=6006" \
          "\nThen open http://0.0.0.0:6006/ into your web browser")
```

**model.py**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import numpy as np

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W, stride):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], padding='VALID')

def softmax(x):
    ex = np.exp(x)
    sum_ex = np.sum( np.exp(x))
    return ex/sum_ex

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 66, 200, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,  1])

x_image = x

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 24])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([24])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1, 2) + b_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 24, 36])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([36])strong text

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2, 2) + b_conv2)

W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 36, 48])
b_conv3 = bias_variable([48])

h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv2, W_conv3, 2) + b_conv3)

W_conv4 = weight_variable([3, 3, 48, 64])
b_conv4 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv3, W_conv4, 1) + b_conv4)

W_conv5 = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 64])
b_conv5 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv4, W_conv5, 1) + b_conv5)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([1152, 1164])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1164])

h_conv5_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv5, [-1, 1152])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_conv5_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1164, 100])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([100])

h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

h_fc2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)

W_fc3 = weight_variable([100, 50])
b_fc3 = bias_variable([50])

h_fc3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc2_drop, W_fc3) + b_fc3)

h_fc3_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc3, keep_prob)

W_fc4 = weight_variable([50, 10])
b_fc4 = bias_variable([10])

h_fc4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc3_drop, W_fc4) + b_fc4)

h_fc4_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc4, keep_prob)

W_fc5 = weight_variable([10, 4])
b_fc5 = bias_variable([4])

y = tf.matmul(h_fc4_drop, W_fc5) + b_fc5

print('model read')
```

**driving_data.py**

```
from cv2 import resize
from imageio import imread
import random
import csv
import config as cfg

xs = []
ys = []

train_batch_pointer = 0
val_batch_pointer = 0

with open('data/' + cfg.currentDir + '/data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        xs.append('data/' + cfg.currentDir + '/' + row[0])
        ys.append(int(row[1]))

num_images = len(xs)

c = list(zip(xs, ys))
random.shuffle(c)
xs, ys = zip(*c)
"""
train_xs = xs[:int(len(xs) * 0.8)]
train_ys = ys[:int(len(xs) * 0.8)]

val_xs = xs[-int(len(xs) * 0.2):]
val_ys = ys[-int(len(xs) * 0.2):]

"""
train_xs = xs[:int(len(xs) * 1)]
train_ys = ys[:int(len(xs) * 1)]

val_xs = xs[-int(len(xs) * 1):]
val_ys = ys[-int(len(xs) * 1):]


num_train_images = len(train_xs)
num_val_images = len(val_xs)

def LoadTrainBatch(batch_size):
    global train_batch_pointer
    x_out = []
    y_out = []
    for i in range(0, batch_size):
        x_out.append(resize(imread(train_xs[(train_batch_pointer + i) % num_train_images])[cfg.modelheight:], [66, 200]) / 255.0)
        y_out.append([train_ys[(train_batch_pointer + i) % num_train_images]])
    train_batch_pointer += batch_size
    return x_out, y_out

def LoadValBatch(batch_size):
    global val_batch_pointer
    x_out = []
    y_out = []
    for i in range(0, batch_size):
        x_out.append(resize(imread(val_xs[(val_batch_pointer + i) % num_val_images])[cfg.modelheight:], [66, 200]) / 255.0)
        y_out.append([val_ys[(val_batch_pointer + i) % num_val_images]])
    val_batch_pointer += batch_size
    return x_out, y_out
```

Comment: Seems the second and third dimensions are swapped in one of them. You need to figure out if the *`value`* or the placeholder has the correct shape and go back and fix the non-compliant one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove python 3.10.5 and
After installing 3.6.8, I entered the following command and it worked fine.

````
python.exe -m pip install -U pip
python.exe -m pip install tensorflow==1.15.0 tensorboard==1.15.0 scipy==1.2.0 urllib3==1.13.1 Pillow opencv-python```
````